# How to convert a list of strings and numbers to float in python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to get data from a csv file which I have done and have appended the data to a list but don't know how to make the entire list into a float.

I tried the following code and it did not work:

```
import csv 

with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[6]
    new_list = []
    for i in lines:
        print(lines)
        new_list.append(float(i))
        print(new_list)
```

I got a ValueError message. ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"' which is weird since I don't understand where it is getting the " from.

The CSV file I am using is from Bureau Of Economic, here's the link to the exact file I am using: https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=19&step=2#reqid=19&step=2&isuri=1&1921=survey

Comment: I see `import csv` but unusued.  You might want to use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Comment: I did use csv.reader in my actual assignment file, and it returned an error which is different from this one (TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list') . Here is a link to a gist if you are interested in looking at the code: https://gist.github.com/roshanlam/f332fcb6ae84836727c737740b5e3378

Comment: The issue (as has been pointed out) is that your csv file is not being loaded correctly, or is has incorrect formatting, or you are indexing the incorrect column.

Comment: wild guess: make sure you are not trying to process the header line of your csv as actual data.

Comment: I am not trying to process the header line of my csv, I wrote a line of code for that `lines = file.readlines()[6]` and I have printed out the result and it gives me what I was expecting.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that `float` is throwing `ValueError`.  This can only mean that you passed it incompatible input.  I would just interrogate `i` to find out why it is not parsable into a float.  Try `print(f'[{i}]')` before you cast it into float.  I expect `[]` to be printed.  Failing that, I expect that the csv is feeding you some invisible characters (e.g. control characters), perhaps.  You will have to sanitize it, if so.

Comment: The URL you link to does not link to an exact file. With `curl` I get an empty download. With Chrome I get a page telling me to enable Javascript. When I enable Javascript for this site I get a listing of resources I could download. I don't think we need a precise link but we need to be able to figure out what exactly to download.

Comment: you need to download the file to work with it, atleast that's what I did.

Comment: Yeah, but which file? The link doesn't take me to a file.

Comment: Section 1 - Table 1.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute `lines = f.readlines()[6]` you are grabbing only the seventh line of the file.  That is only one line and it is a `str` (string) that contains that whole line from the file.  As you go through and try to iterate `for i in lines` you are actually going through the seventh line of the file, character-by-character and attempting to do the `float()` conversion.  The first character of that line is the `"` which is causing the error.

In order to go through all of the lines of the file *starting with* the seventh line you need to change the array indexing to `lines = f.readlines()[6:]`.  That gets you to processing the lines, one-by-one.

But, that's all a sort of explanation of what was going on.  As @Razzle Shazl points out, you're not using the CSV reader.

That said, I think this is what you're actually trying to accomplish:

```
import csv

with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for i in range(6):  # this is to skip over header rows in the data (I saw 6 in the file I downloaded)
        next(csv_data)

    for row in csv_data:  # going through the rest of the rows of data
        new_list = []
        for i in range(2, len(row)):  # go through each column after the line number and description
            new_list.append(float(row[i]))  # convert element to float and append to array
        print(f"CSV Input: {row}")
        print(f"Converted: {new_list}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert empty string to float. Probably somewhere the data is empty.

```
In [1]: float("")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-603e80e58999> in <module>
----> 1 float("")

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If you want to ignore the exception and continue processing, then use `try/except` block